# FInd invalid email address

Tags: mysql

How to find invalid email address in a row with SELECT ?

Comment: The **only** way to determine email address validity with 100% certainty is to send mail to it.

Comment: What programming language are you using to query the database? Also, what you mean invalid? That doesn't exist? Invalid syntax?

Comment: +1 it's a valid question, no reason to downvote it

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx, how will you answer this question?

Comment: What is I mean is to select rows in table which are not valid email address such fooo@com foo.bar.com etc.

Comment: @Starx, I won't answer, I'm about to go to sleep. I just hate seeing valid questions downvoted for no good reason.

Comment: @georgevich, fooo@com is technically valid, though unlikely.

Comment: @georgevich: Define ***exactly*** how you want to validate an email. It's the only way you will get a proper answer, there is a lot of (warranted) disagreement on how to properly validate an email address.

Comment: @duedl0r define invalid? : not respecting the format as specified in RFC 822 and later

Comment: @Charles The only way to determine email address validity with 100% certainty is to send mail to it: wrong, he's asking for valid address not "active" or "existing"...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT
    email
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    email NOT LIKE '%_@_%._%'
AND email NOT LIKE '%list of invalid char%';
```

Comment: !@#$%^&*.asdfsdafasd is not a valid email address

Comment: @Michael you are correct, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Everything after the AND part doesn't make sense, first of all I think you meant email LIKE and second doesn't the invalid characters each need their own clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT email FROM tablename WHERE email NOT REGEXP '(^[a-z0-9]+)\@(.*)'
```

Comment: -1 `local.part_can+be-more%complex@example.com` disagrees with you. See the infamous (but mostly correct) regex at ex-parrot: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Too strict in some ways, too lax in others.

Comment: maybe something like this? `(^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-_a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$)|(^$)`

Comment: That match even valid email address

Comment: @Michael Koper: `info@правительство.рф` disagrees (and it would not work in punycode either: `info@xn--80aealotwbjpid2k.xn--p1ai`)

Comment: I guess try the regexes from here then? http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @lobster1234: I guess that's outdated (no IDN); plus the author says "I know it's too strict and rejects valid addresses, but I just don't care".

Comment: omg, it doesn't make sense to argue about the correct regex. everybody knows there is not an easy solution to this. just accept the theoretical way how to handle it with mysql and find a suitable regex for your needs.